# Get Web Analytics

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

Is there any way to export the Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell?

The following link shows an example of the data I would like to retrieve, both on (Web collection and site collection) level.

[http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349%2D3bb6%2D4087%2D94f4%2D7f95ff4ca81f&ID=250&Web=48e6fdd1%2D17db%2D4543%2Db2f9%2D6fc7185484fc](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=250&Web=48e6fdd1-17db-4543-b2f9-6fc7185484fc)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably export from the Analytics Reporting [database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx).

Default database name = "Search_Service_Application_AnalyticsReportingStoreDB_[GUID]"

Comment: Do you have any example of a SQL query that would allow me to do this?